# Blocking a submission to MySQL if conditions are met

Tags: php, mysql

The code below works well.  It submits some variables into a MySQL database.  How could I block the submission and redirect the user back to `domain.com/index.php` if the  conditions below are met?

Conditions:

- `$uid` has been used more 11 or more times in a calendar day.
- `$cleanurl` has ever been used before.

Thanks in advance,

John

Code:

```
 if(isURL($site1)==true)
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO submission VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$title', '$slug', '$cleanurl', '$displayurl', NULL)");
    else
     echo "<p class=\"topicu\">Not a valid URL.</p>\n";
```

Comment: You should be using parameterized sql queries and not string interpolation. Your code allows sql injection attacks.

Comment: This is a great primer on using PHP's PDO extension to work with a database using prepared/parametrized queries: http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html

Answer (score 1):

$uid has been used more 11 or more times in a calendar day:

`select uid from submissions where date > '$todaysDate 00:00' and date < '$todaysDate 23:59' group by uid having count() > 11`

$cleanurl has ever been used before.

`SELECT count(*) from ... where cleanurl='$cleanurl'`

if both conditions are met, then

`Header("Location: http://domain.com/index.php");`

Comment: Thanks... how do I make the variable for $todayDate?

Answer (score -1):

You would simply need to run queries to apply these checks prior to your INSERT and if the criteria isn't met, forward them on as you mentioned.

[REMOVED STUPID COMMENT]

mysql_real_escape_string() is definitely the route to take

Comment: No, no, heck no.  You should either use prepared queries or a function like `mysql_real_escape_string()` to quote dangerous characters.  You should not switch quoting styles in an attempt to combat SQL injection...  **Edit:**  I do agree with the first line in your answer.  That is a typical solution to this kind of "problem"...

Comment: Or even better, use prepared statements with mysqli or similar.